# How to use Laravel function in regular php

Tags: php, function, laravel

This is pretty basic question. I have a function in in laravel:

`{{This::function('arg1', 'arg2')}}`

Now I need to use it inside of echo in regular php but im not sure how exactly are these laravel's one built:

```
<?php
echo "blablabla This::function('arg1', 'arg2') blabla";
?>
```

How to correctly do it?

Comment: What exactly is `This::function`?

Comment: @DavidBarker It is some function that changes style of the arg2 text. Honestly i cannot find it in project. I was just using it so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **concatenation operator** to join 3 string values:

```
echo "blablabla " . This::function('arg1', 'arg2') . " blabla";
```

or just make use of the fact that echo accepts multiple arguments and will output all of them:

```
echo "blablabla ", This::function('arg1', 'arg2'), " blabla";
```

Comment: You are right but `This::function` seems to make some errors in my php code. Shouldnt it be wrote other way? without this double colon?

Comment: I don't know what this function is, please post some more code. In general "this/function" is a reserved keyword in php and you shouldn't name your classes/functions like that.

Comment: It is some function that changes style of the text which is arg2. Honestly i cannot find it in project. I was just using it so far